# Trying to install a package, throwing errors

Tags: wireless, drivers, apt, software-installation, atheros

```
apt-get install firmware-atheros
```

Throws me an error. I've already changed sources.list to allow non-free.

```
(Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 219877 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-atheros_0.36+wheezy.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-atheros (0.36+wheezy.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /home/administrator/Downloads/firmware-atheros_0.36+wheezy.1_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ath3k-1.fw', which is also in package linux-firmware 1.138.1
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal gzip write error: Broken pipe
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/home/administrator/Downloads/firmware-atheros_0.36+wheezy.1_all.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
```

Happens. Is there a way I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: What do you need the firmware for?

Comment: Looks as if the firmware is already installed "trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ath3k-1.fw', which is also in package linux-firmware 1.138.1" so remove that package first perphps or file a bug report

Comment: It's to make my TL-WN821N USB WiFi dongle work. @Jeremy31

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that stopped the error throwing, thanks!

Comment: OK, you may want to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: What does `lsusb` tell us about the dongle?

Comment: Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0cf3:7015 Atheros Communications, Inc. TP-Link TL-WN821N v3 802.11n [Atheros AR7010+AR9287]

Comment: @Jeremy31 see above

Comment: It should have worked with the `linux-firmware` package.  Try rebooting with it unplugged and plug it in after boot is complete

Comment: @Jeremy31 it DOES work, with both, but it drops every few minutes. I'll try that, give me a minute.

Comment: Droppin wifi might be from TKIP or WEP being enabled on the wifi access point. `iwlist scan` should tell you if you are using `CCMP` which is what I have no problems with or a mixed mode with `CCMP TKIP` that has issues

Comment: @Jeremy31 http://pastebin.com/LV1ES083. It looks like I'm using mixed: how would I change?

Comment: You will need to access the routers setup and find the encryption settings.  I find my routers IP address by looking at the gateway address from `route -n` and entering it in my browser.  Then enter username and password for access to settings

Comment: @Jeremy31 I can't find a setting to change that in the BT Hub 3 settings, unless you mean WPA/WPA2 etc? I've got that set to WPA/WPA2 using default password.

Comment: You must be close if you see WPA/WPA2 settings, try WPA2 only to see if TKIP is removed

Comment: @Jeremy31 that's fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the problem was solved by removing the conflicting package

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-firmware
```

Comment: It fixed the problem (throwing an error) but I can't get the package to work: it keeps dropping.